# RewriteEngine appends /%25/ to my directory http->https

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, mod-rewrite

I have my configuration file set up like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/%$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /ssd/www/
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /ssd/certs/example_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssd/certs/example_com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /ssd/certs/example_com.ca-bundle
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when navigating to a standard HTTP page when it redirects it appends `/%25/` to the domain, so for example..

`http://example.com` is changed to `https://example.com/%25/` 
and `http://example.com/my-category/my-page` is changed to `https://example.com/%25/my-category/my-page`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Line 4 should be:

```
RewriteRule (.*) mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

%25 is the URL encoded value of %

Comment: That was it, thanks; Wonder why so many tutorials have `%$1` I'll mark this as accepted when I can

Comment: "why so many tutorials have `%$1`" - I'm curious, can you link to one or two please? (`%1` (no dollar) is a backreference to the last matched _CondPattern_ - is that possibly where the confusion comes from?)

Answer (score 1):

As Vikelidis has already pointed out, `%$1` is in error. However, you have other issues that should also be addressed.

The `RewriteCond` directive checking for HTTPS (ie. port 443) in the `VirtualHost` for port 80 is redundant and should be removed.

Also, when used in the server config, the `RewriteRule` pattern matches against the full URL-path, which *includes* the slash prefix. Your substitution will then result in a double slash. Apache collapses this later to resolve the request, however, it is still available in some cases, so could break later rules.

This redirect should also be a permanent 301, not a temporary 302 (the default) - but only change it when you are sure it's working OK.

So, if using mod_rewrite, this should be written as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule /(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then again, you don't need mod_rewrite at all here. A mod_alias `Redirect` would be more efficient:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Agreed, if you already have an `HTTP` virtual host there is no need to use mod_rewrite.